# Tooltip positioning with jQuery's .offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

## UPDATE - Still unresolved, last updated 9 p.m.

## Problem

**a)** How do I use .offset() to position these tooltips relatively close to their image (ie. If I click on the "Allum" headshot, their tooltip pops up above their image)

### Where I'm at

I'm trying to use jQuery's `.offset()` so that when an image `(.headshot in index.html)` of a politician is clicked, the tooltip/popup, containing information about their age, party etc. is positioned pretty close to their image. Right now I have dynamic content being pulled into these tooltips, but it's always in the same spot.

## scripts.js (Politician and Positioning snippet)

```
// Shows a popup with MLA information
$(".headshot").click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index();

    $(".tooltip").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".tooltipName").html(MLAs[idx].Name);
    $(".tooltipParty").html(MLAs[idx].Party).prepend("<strong>Party: </strong>");
    $(".tooltipConstuency").html(MLAs[idx].Constuency).prepend("<strong>Constuency: </strong>");
    $(".tooltipEthnicity").html(MLAs[idx].Ethnicity).prepend("<strong>Ethnicity: </strong>");
    $(".tooltipAge").html(MLAs[idx].Age).prepend("<strong>Age: </strong>").append(" years old");
});


// Positioning of the tooltips
$('img').each(function(){
    var img = $(this);

    img.click(function(){
        $('.tooltip').show(100)
        // .text(img.attr('alt'))
        .offset({
            top: img.offset().top + img.height(),
            left: img.offset().left
        });
    });
});
```

### index.html(Headshot snippet)

```
<div class="columns">
                    <img src="assets/img/headshots/allan.jpg" alt="" id="0" class="headshot NDP Female White">
                    <img src="assets/img/headshots/allum.jpg" alt="" id="1" class="headshot NDP Male White">
                    <img src="assets/img/headshots/altemeyer.jpg" alt="" id="2" class="headshot NDP Male White">
</div>
```

### tooltip.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
TOOLTIP
----------------------------------*/

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 45px;
    top: -5px;
}

.info {
    @include serifLight;
    background: $yellow;
    color: $black;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 15%;
    // text-align: center;

    p {
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 2%;
    }
}

.tooltipName, {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.label {
    color: $b;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
}

.tooltipEthnicity, .tooltipAge {
    display: block;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid $yellow;
    position: relative;
    left: 29px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  var   position = $el.data('.elem'),
        ImagePosition = $el.offset(),
        ImageSize = {
          'width': $el.outerWidth(),
          'height': $el.outerHeight()
        };

'top': ImagePosition.top - el.outerHeight() 
'left': ImagePosition.left - (elelment.outerWidth()/2) + (elementSize.width/2)
```

Comment: Getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` Also curious if you tried running your snippet in a JSFiddle?